# Im using bookmark to load js file

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm using a bookmark to load `js` file.

And the problem I'm facing is my bookmark does not check for update in the `js` file.

```
javascript:(function(){
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script'))
        .src='http://mysite.com/pet.js';
})();
```

Do I have to add something in bookmark? Or does I need to add in a `js` file?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browser might be loading that from cache, so to get rid of cache issue.

```
javascript:(function(){
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script'))
        .src='http://mysite.com/pet.js?'+Math.random();
})();
```

Comment: Why not `+new Date()` instead?